# What exactly is USB Bluetooth adapter firmware used for?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, firmware

I recently learned that Linux tries to find a "firmware file" when a USB Bluetooth adapter is connected and usually reports an error in `dmesg` is this file is not found (e.g. see [this question on another SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449212/bluetooth-firmware-rtl8821a-fw-bin-fails-to-load-in-debian)).

However, it seems that most adapters work perfectly fine without this file. [Plugable even specifically says this error can be ignored](https://kb.plugable.com/680389/bluetooth-headphones-speaker-or-headset-isnt-working-in-windows-linux):

> Some users may notice that there are issues relating to missing firmware for the Bluetooth adapter in the system logs on Linux. This is normal, and **the error can be ignored as it has no impact on the actual functionality of the adapter**.

If this "firmware file" has nothing to do with actual functionality, what's the purpose of it in general? What kind of functionality is contained in this firmware as opposed to the driver itself?

Comment: Please give the names for specific missing files. The question as written is too broad.

Comment: Cross site duplicate https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300404/what-are-firmware-blobs-from-linux-firmware-exactly it might be that the device has a "just about works" firmware built in, but to work fully or get updates a new blob is written into the devices program memory which is often a 64kByte of RAM that it uses to do all its work.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the broader idea behind this, rather than something Linux-specific. I guess the Ubuntu question does have this answer, sort of, but I'm still curious why e.g. Windows requires it, but Linux doesn't.

Comment: A Bluetooth device can be almost anything, e.g. keyboard, headset or cell phone. Firmware sets up devices for use and provides settings.